# How to read 20 lines at a time in C?

Tags: c

I need to write a program for school and I am having some trouble with getting the program to read and display 20 lines of the file. after the 20 lines are read for the first time I need to click enter and then another 20 lines need to be displayed (It can be less than 20 lines if there are less lines left in the file so it needs to be able to read that too).
Now it prints the first line forever in an endless loop.
What am I doing wrong?

```
char line[100];
char len[100];
i = 1;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), outfile) != 0) {
    while (sscanf(line, "%s", len) == 1) {
        printf("%d: %s", i++, line);
    }
}
```

The problem with displaying 20 lines for the first time has been fixed. Under here is the solution.

```
char line[100];
i = 1;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), outfile) != 0 && i <= 20) {
        printf("%d: %s", i++, line);
}
```

Now I just need to get it to give me an option to press enter and then it will display 20 more lines. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: `sscanf(line, "%s", len)`. That will produce the same result every time it is called. It's not like `scanf` that consumes the input. The same `line` variable is parsed every time it is called. Don't call it in a loop.

Comment: Ohhhh I did not know that. Do you know an alternative I can use?

Comment: Use for what? You already have a loop calling `fgets`. Don't see why you need another loop. But what exactly are you trying to do with the `sscanf`? The line is already contained in `line` after calling `fgets`. You can print out the whole line with `printf(line)` without the `sscanf`.

Comment: Well I want 20 lines to be displayed at a time (It are 110 lines total). But when I only used the fgets it would display all of them at once.

Comment: Just have in the loop `if (i++ == 20) break;` That is, keep calling `fgets` to read one line at a time and have a counter for each line read. When the counter reaches 20 you can break out of the loop. Or add the condition to the `while`: `while (fgets(..) != NULL && i++ < 20)`.I don't see how `sscanf` helps in any way to achieve what you want anyway.

Comment: Thank youuu! This already helped a lot. I removed the `sscanf` and put the `&& i <= 20` in there and now it will display 20 lines. Now I need to get it to give me an option to press enter and then it will display 20 more lines. Do you have an idea how this could be done? @kaylum

Comment: Don't even use fgets. It is unnecessarily complicated.  Read (and output) one character at a time, incrementing a counter when you see a new line.  When you see the 20th newline, block on a read from the terminal.

Comment: Why are you reading from a file named `outfile`?  Names are important, and that's just confusing.

Comment: Well the `fgets` part is already figured out so I don't see why I would change it now. The only problem left is how do I get it to display 20 more lines everytime I press enter. @William Pursell (Still thanks for the comment :) )

Comment: The file is not named outfile. `outfile = fopen(argv[1], "r");` I did this because it being displayed is the output of the file on the screen. as input would be `scanf` (from the keyboard) and output would be `printf` (To the screen).

Comment: `outfile = fopen(argv[1], "r")` is a poor name.  If the file is being opened for reading, it makes no sense to name the variable `outfile`.

Comment: You can also use `tcgetattr()/tcsetattr()` to put the keyboard in raw mode so you can use `space` or `Enter` to page and also take input like `'c'` to continue-to-end or `'q'` quit at that point, etc.. You can take additional arguments to turn line-numbering on/off, etc..

Comment: Okay the teacher put it in like that so I thought it would be an alright name. @William Pursell also what name would you put in because I have no idea what would be a good name.

Comment: Ohhh okay. I haven't had that in class but I will try to find out how it works. Thanks :) @David C. Rankin

Comment: @Hawk. Since it's an input stream, it seems that something like `infile` would be appropriate.

Comment: @Hawk, I put together a quick example in [C - 20 Line Pager w/Line Numbers and Continue/Quit](https://pastebin.com/3JyJ5Emv) if you would like to see the use of *cooked* (normal) verses *raw* (non-canonical) mode and a way of advancing the pager with any whitespace press, allowing `'c'` to continue to end and `'q'` (or manual `EOF`) to quit, that's a reasonably commented example. Provide filename to read as 1st argument on command-line, any 2nd argument enables line-number of paged output.

Answer (score 1):

`while (sscanf(line, "%s", len) == 1)` will run infinite or no times because you don't update the contents of `line` in the loop and the result will always be same.

You should use `if` instead of `while` to do branch only once and proceed to reading of next line.

Also it seems you forgot to add a newline character in your printing.

Try this:

```
char line[100];
char len[100];
i = 1;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), outfile) != 0) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%s", len) == 1) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i++, line);
    }
}
```

Note that contents after the first whitespace character will be removed thanks to the `%s` specifier.

Comment: I had tried this already but this will display all the lines in the file but I only want 20 displayed at a time and when I press enter another 20 need to appear (It needs to work with less than 20 lines as well)

Answer (score 0):

In a sort of pidgin C-like dialect to pronounce the logic without finishing your school assignment for you:

```
file := open("MyFile", READ)
if (file) {
    c := 0
    while (c != EOF && more(file, 20)) {
          while (getchar(&c) && c != '\n') {
          }
    }
    close(file)
}
more(file, nlines) {
    c := 0
    while getchar(file, &c) {
         putchar(c)
         if (c == '\n' && --nlines == 0) {
              return 1
         }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I haven't seen everything of this in class so i'll take some time to figure out how everything works here and then implement it.